# Laravel CRUD Builder module view fatal error

Tags: laravel, syntax

When I create a module and then try and view the module I get this below exception:

syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

**app/storage/framework/views/4bcd2699f37708697d1e4719620c2ac5 line 75**

This is on line 75:

```
<td width="50"><input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="<?  php echo e($row->); ?>" />  </td>
```

And I get this on every new module I create.

My PHP is 5.6
Laravel is 5.1.1

Comment: `<?  php echo e($row->); ?>` why there is space between `<?` and `php`. Also what is `e($row->)`. Your whole syntax is wrong

Comment: It's in a template that seems to be generated when you make a module I think it has something to do with display records from the db??

Answer (score 0):

You are viewing the .php file created from your .blade.php file. Kindly check your .blade.php file that corresponds to the 4bcd2699f37708697d1e4719620c2ac5.php file. 
You will come to know this by reading the first few lines of the .php file. There seems to be an error in the .blade.php file. Kindly post that.

I can't comment yet so posting this as an answer.